# Enabling a OSGi/RCP plugin to load a class from another, non-dependent, plugin

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-rcp, classloader, gridgain

I have a set of three RCP plug-ins: one is my main application plugin, another is a collection of calculations, and a third is a wrapper for GridGain, which among other things has to create instances of classes from the calculation plugin.

The main plug-in instantiates classes from both the calculation and GridGain plugin using ExtensionPoint instantiation, eg:

```
    IExtensionRegistry registry = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();

    IExtensionPoint providerExtensionPoint = registry.getExtensionPoint(EXT_CORE_DATA_PROVIDERS);
    IConfigurationElement[] providers = providerExtensionPoint.getConfigurationElements();

    List<DataProviderFactory> dataProviders = new ArrayList<DataProviderFactory>();
    for (IConfigurationElement member : providers) {
        try {
            Object obj = member.createExecutableExtension(K_CLASS);
            if (obj instanceof DataProviderFactoryFactory) {
                DataProviderFactoryFactory factory = (DataProviderFactoryFactory) obj;
                for (Object o : factory.createProviderFactories(this, holdingProperties())) {
                    dataProviders.add((DataProviderFactory) o);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    return dataProviders;
```

and thus has no direct dependencies on the other plugins.

My problem arises when GridGain has to instantiate instances of classes from the calculation plugin.  Since the GridGain plugin has no direct dependency on the calculation plugin, it's class-loading process doesn't see classes there, so I get a ClassNotFoundException.

I've solved similar problems in the past using [RCP buddy policies](http://rajakannappan.blogspot.com/2010/03/eclipse-classloading-and-buddy-policy.html), and this seems to be a problem similar to what you face with an ORM.  However, the 'registered' policy depends on the fact that that the plugin that defines the classes (calculation plugin, in my case) has a dependency on the plugin that instantiates them (GridGain plugin).  In my scenario, there is no such dependency.  So adding BuddyPolicy: registered to GridGain and RegisterBuddy: gridgain to the calculations plugin doesn't work.

The only way I've found to make the GridGain plugin resolve classes from the calculation plugin is to explicitly define GridGain as having a dependency on calculation.  To my mind, that shouldn't be necessary, there should be a way of having this be a soft dependency where if the calculation plugin is present, GridGain can instantiate classes from it.  Is there another way to model this interdependency so that my classloading issues go away?

Answer (score 1):

There is should be some way of dependency from GridGain plugin on your calculations plugin. GridGain will not have access to calculations classes if you don't define any dependency. I can think of this, create another plugin ( base plugin) with common interfaces and make GridGain and Calculations depend on base plugin. Expose declarative services in Calculations plugin for the interfaces that you define in base plugin.

In GridGain plugin, use osgi `ServiceTracker` to wait the services exposed in Calculations plugin.

Comment: In this case though GridGain doesn't need to interact with the implementations, just instantiate them during it's unmarshalling.  This is more like Hibernate needing to instantiate business objects and then pass them to the application.

Answer (score 1):

There are two safe ways to instantiate classes from another bundle without importing its packages.

In most cases you want an implementation for an interface you know. For this case a good style is to create a factory for the class in the bundle that knows the impl and publish it e.g. using an OSGi service. Inside the factory the class can then be instanciated using new.

The other way is to use the classloader of the bundle that knows the impl. In this case you have to use an interface that allows to retrieve the classloader of the other bundle. Then you can just load the class by its name.

Comment: I don't think the first approach is relevant for this, as GG isn't interested in keeping references to the instantiated objects, it's just responsible for instantiating them and passing them off to the rest of the app.  The second suggestion is equivalent to having an optional dependency, right?  The GG plugin would still have to be aware specifically of the calculation plugin.

Comment: Am I correct that you want a dynamic list of DataProviderFactories populated with the Factories from calculation and GridGain? If yes then the service aproach may be ideal. Simply let calculation and GridGain create their factories in their Activator and register them as an OSGi service. Then you bundle can get the list of services of the DataFactory interface and simply go through it. You then do not need the extension point anymore.

Comment: That's not quite right, perhaps my original question wasn't well phrased. The main plugin instantiates DataProviderFactories via ExtensionPoints.  The Gridgain plugin would receive an instruction to instantiate an instance of a class by name (eg 'com.company.DataProviderFactoryImpl).  Internally to the GridGain product (ie not in OSGi or RCP-aware code), Class.forName(name) gets called, which fails because the plug-in classloader doesn't know about the calculations plugin where com.company.DataProviderImpl is declared.

Comment: In this case this is a problem in the Gridgain product. If you have any influence on them try to make them provide an api where you can supply a classloader and a class name. Then it will be easy. In this case DynamicImport-Package may be another work around. You can use it for the bundle that contaimns the GridGain jar. So it will see all classes. THe problem is only that you do not have much control over what it sees. So I see this only as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Make the dependency on calculation plugin optional.
2. Use `Import-Package` instead of `Require-Bundle` (again, possibly optional) if you know the package name in advance.
3. Use [`DynamicImport-Package`](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/DynamicImport-Package), but this should be avoided in most cases.

Comment: 1. is what i'm doing now.  2 sounds basically the same for my purposes, I don't expect these implementations to be swapped out for another plugin so referring to package name or bundle name is basically the same to me.  DynamicImport I'm not familiar with, will look in to it.  I assume it's similar to the intention of eclipse buddy policy global?